# guardar la suma de varios resultados de una consulta en una variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo el resultado de una consulta. 
 Por ejemplo `100,-90,120,450,-45,5`.
lo que necesito es sumar `100,120,450,5 (positivos)` y guardar el resultado en una variable, por ejemplo `$resultadopositivo=675`. 
Por otro lado sumar `-90,-45 (negativos)` y guardar en otra variable, por ejemplo `$resultadonegativo= -135.`
 ¿Eso se puede hacer de alguna manera? 
Gracias.

Comment: todo esto es usando php y mysql

Comment: Si se puede hacer de alguna manera.

Comment: bueno, como????

Comment: Bienvenido @Luis Maldonado, te recomiendo hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas como formular preguntas [ask] y sean bien aceptadas.